Do there exist 4th+ order ODEs whose solutions are closed under composition?
Motivation:
This question originates from the general idea of exploring "what groups BIGGER than the Mobius transformations" act on $\mathbb{C}$.
We can start by considering simple ODEs whose solutions are closed under composition. (Here $y = y(x)$)

$y=x$, this is a 0th order ODE and has a complex 0-dimensional solution set $y(x) = x$. This represents the trivial group.
$y'=1$ , this is a 1st order ODE and has complex 1-dimensional solution set $y(x) = x - A$ over all complex numbers $A$. This represents the group $(\mathbb{C},+)$.
$y'' = 0$. This is a 2nd order ODE and has complex 2-dimensional solution set $y(x) = Ax + B$. This represents the group $\text{Aff}(1, \mathbb{C})$.
$ \left( \sqrt{\frac{1}{y'}}\right)'' = 0 $. This is a 3rd order ODE and has a complex 3 dimensional solution set $y(x) = \frac{Ax+B}{Cx+D}$. This represents the group $\text{PGL}(2, \mathbb{C})$.  (Well to be honest I can verify the general mobius group  obeys the ODE but I haven't yet proven NO other solutions exist).  This ODE can be shown to be equivalent to $3(y'')^2 - 2y'''y'=0$ and the latter is easily solved using elementary techniques, moreover it's easy to verify the composition property even without solving the ODE.

Question:
What is an example of a 4th or higher degree ODE whose collection of solutions is closed under composition and forms a 4+ complex dimensional solution set?
Some Thoughts:
We can start by asking how the list I provided above was made.
I've more or less just "guessed" these solutions using mangled intuition and playing with the expected solution set. And once an ODE was found we can then verify that if $f, g$ obey the target ODE then $f(g(x))$ must obey it as well.
This question is a bit hard for me because I don't apriori HAVE any idea of what my solution set will look like. So that reverse engineering can't happen here. There needs to be some machinery to verify that if $f,g$ obey our 4th order ODE then $f(g(x))$ obeys it as well BUT (it is likely) that the ODE itself will not have elementary closed form solutions.
Restatement as a Polynomial Functional Equation:
We are seeking an operator $H(y,y',y'',y''', y'''', ...)$ s.t. the solution set given by $H(y,y',y'',y''', y'''', ...)=0$ is closed under composition. This can be restated as:
Given:
$$ H(f(x), f'(x), ... f''''(x)) = 0 \\ H(g(x), g'(x), ... g''''(x)) = 0$$
It must be that
$$ H(f(g(x)), f(g(x))', ... f(g(x))'''') = 0 $$
Via the chain rule the bottom can be expanded to:
$$ H(f(g(x)), f'(g(x))g'(x), f''(g(x))(g'(x))^2 + f'(g(x))g''(x) ... ) = 0 $$
If we assume that H is a multivariate polynomial of its arguments then this can be written as follows
Given
$$H(a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4) = 0 \\ H(b_0, b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4) = 0$$
It must be that
$$ H(a_0, a_1b_1, a_2b_1^2 + a_1b_2, a_3 (b_1)^3 + 3a_2 b_1 b_2 + a_1 b_3, ...) = 0$$
This is equivalent to stating that there exist polynomials $e_1(a_0 ... a_4, b_0 ... b_4)$ and $e_2(a_0 ... a_4, b_0 ... b_4)$ s.t.
$$ H(a_0, a_1b_1, a_2b_1^2 + a_1b_2, ...) = e_1 H(a_0, ... a_4) + e_2 H(b_0, ... b_4) $$
So this reduces to a functional equation asking "do there exist polynomials $H, e_1, e_2$ satisfying the above functional equation?"

Just mentioning that your differential equation for the Möbius transformations is closely related to the Schwarzian derivative.

Thanks for the link! I didn't realize it was so well known!  The part about pseudogroups is beyond my technical understanding but there is a section that seems interesting  "A flat pseudogroup Γ is said to be "defined by differential equations" if there is a finite integer k ..." followed by "The only possibilities in this case are that k = 1... k = 2". I'm not sure if i'm reading too far into something I don't understand but it seems like these might be the ONLY possible groups and my question therefore does not have an answer.

To complete Martin's comment, the kernel of the Schwarzian derivative $S$ contains the Möbius transformations (and only them); see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3954146/schwarz-derivative-and-m%c3%b6bius-transformation for instance. In consequence, the differential equation you are looking for is simply $Sf = 0$.
